# Neo4j: "ghost" node in label index throws error

Tags: indexing, neo4j, label

I have a neo4j database with a set of nodes with label :EXAMPLE.

There are two operations. First I delete one node and then I look for another one. They are done separately using neo4j API.

```
MATCH (n:EXAMPLE {Name: { name1 }}) DELETE n;
```

and

```
MATCH (n:EXAMPLE {Name: { name2 }}) RETURN n;
```

Sometimes, when I execute second query, it throws an error *"Node with id 123"*. Node with id 123 is **the same** node that was deleted in the **first query**.

It happens when there is a lot of requests are coming to the database simultaneously.

---

I guess that it could happen if node was deleted, but EXAMPLE label index wasn't updated yet. There are two facts that prove such theory.

1) The error is unstable.

2) If I change second query like this (remove the label), I won't get the error:

```
MATCH (n {Name: { name2 }}) RETURN n;
```

---

Neo4j version is 2.1.5, Java - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-2~deb7u1) and operation system is Debian. There are no other indexes in the database except the label.

The question is how can I fix this, but still use labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible workaround:

Mark nodes as deleted instead of deleting. Ignore nodes that are marked as deleted. Delete all such nodes at once with a garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

What ends up happening is that (simplified) the operations will order like so:

```
Q1: MATCH (n)
Q2: DELETE (n), COMMIT
Q1: RETURN n # Error, n no longer exists
```

For implementation reasons, this is much more likely to happen if cypher is going via an index. The database will eventually handle this for you, but for now, you'll need to wrap that read query in a retry block - if it fails with this type of error, you simply run it again.

On that note, there are other errors that are easily recoverable from by retrying, such as deadlock errors, so wrapping your statements and/or transactions in retry-blocks is a useful thing to do in general.

Comment: This solution does not look very efficient. Retry blocks are fine for connection errors, but not for database errors. The database should internally resolve such situations with proper locks.

Comment: By the way, it looks that you got wrong what is my real problem. The simplified order is:
`Q1: DELETE (n)`
`Q2: MATCH (m) # Error, n no longer exists`
I do not look for **n** in second query, but it still remains in label index, and therefore throws an error.